# The number of ways of seating three gentleman and three ladies in a row ,such that each gentleman is adjacent to at least one lady

Tags: combinatorics

The number of ways of seating three gentleman and three ladies in a row ,such that each gentleman is adjacent to at least one lady, is

***My try :***

If we try to find the complement of the situation and subtract it from 6! then it may be easier.

If all the three gentleman are together then at least one will not be adjacent to any lady.

If all the three ladies are between any two gentlemen then also the other gentleman is not adjacent to any lady.

But my counting showing error.

Please do provide any handy method else  let me know if I missed any other cases.

Help appreciated :)

Comment: Two gentlemen on one end, the third in an arbitrary position. (GGLGLL, GGLLGL, GGLLLG, and their reverses. You've already accounted for GGGLLL.)

Comment: I think there are $396$ ways

Comment: @ArchisWelankar though you are close enough but its wrong

Comment: Sorry my mistake $360$ ways

Comment: @ArchisWelankar thats it .. but could you plz explain?

Comment: given the answer ask for clarifications if any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See we will go by your method using complements. See total ways are $720$ . now lets group three men so let us assume them $x$ . now let us place them in positions $123$ so total ways are $3!.3!=36$ as men and women can  e arranged amongst in $3!$ ways. Now place $x$ at place $234$ again same number of ways ie $36$ now similarly at $345,456$ so total ways become $36\cdot 4=144$ now group any two men . this can be done in $3$ ways. Place them at place $1,2$ now total ways become $3.2!.3.3!=108$ . men can be arranged in $2!$ ways $3rd$ place has to be female or it becomez similar to $3$ men together so $3$ ways and $1M,2w$ can be arranged in $3!$ ways. Note that now they cant be placed in positions $(23),(34),(45)$ as it becomes similar to $3$ men together. So now they can be placed at $56$ position. Again similar to $12$ position we get $108$ ways . now remember we are talking complement of total permitted ways . hence total ways are $720-144-216=360$

Answer (score 3):

A gentleman will not be adjacent to any lady under the following scenarios:

1. A gentleman is surrounded by two gentlemen on each side.
2. A gentleman is the last person on the right and is preceded by a gentleman who is preceded by a lady.
3. A gentleman is the first person on the left and is followed by a gentleman who is followed by a lady.

For 1). group the three gentlemen together $g_1g_2g_3$ and now permute the three ladies and this group (treating this as the fourth object) which can be done in $4!$ ways. But these three gentlemen can be permuted among themselves in $3!$ ways as well. So a total of $4! \cdot 3!=144$ ways.

For 2). The ending segment of an arrangement should look like $l_ig_ig_j$. Pick the lady in $3$ ways to fill the place for $l_i$, then pick and arrange the two gentlemen $g_ig_j$ in $3.2=6$ ways and fill the first three slots can in $3!$ ways. So in all $(3)(6)(3!)=108$ ways.

For 3). similar to 2). so $108$ ways.

So the number of good cases: $6!-(144+108+108)=720-360=360.$

Answer (score 1):

As we have 6 people we can arrange them in 6! ways.

We need to find those arrangements where a gentleman is adjacent to at least one lady.

Let's find the complement of this situation and subtract it from 6!.

There are two cases in which a gentleman is not adjacent to a lady.

Case 1- All three gentlemen are together.

Combine all three gentlemen to one unit and permute. Again 3 gentlemen can be arranged in 3! ways.

Therefore it can be done in 4!*3! ways. That is 144.

Case 2- Any two gentlemen on one end and the other gentleman can seat in three different places (Note: The third gentleman cant seat adjacent to the two gentlemen we have already placed because this is case 1 where all gentlemen are seating together.)

In both end we can place any two gentlemen.Choose two from three gentlemen. That can be done in C(3,2) ways. Again they can be arranged in 2! ways. so P(3,2)

They can be on the left or right end.so  2 ways.

The third gentleman can be placed in 3 ways.

The ladies can be placed in the rest three positions where they can be arranged in 3! way.

Therefore in total = P(3,2)*2*3*3! =216

So answer will be 720- 144-216=360

Answer (score 0):

*Another way*:

Consider the *maximum* number of gentlemen $(G)$ that can be accommodated among the ladies $(L)$ under the stipulations:

$GLGGLGGLG\;\;$ with the gentlemen occupying $4$ "zones"

We need to remove $3$ gentlemen,
which can either be a block of $GG$ and a $G:2\times3$  or three $G's:\binom43,$ totaling to $10$

Thus permissible arrangements $ = 10\times 3!\times 3! = 360$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that 3 women is in a row, which gives us 4 positions for the gentlemen to be seated. In order to satisfy the situation that each gentleman is adjacent to at least one lady, we can seat at most 2 gentlemen in between and 1 gentlemen at the both sides.

Thus, we can put gentlemen in 3 or 2 positions, the number of the total ways is:
$$
3!(3!\times C_4^3 + 3\times 2\times 2 \times 2! + 3\times 2 \times 2!)= 360 
$$